# Translating this monadic counter from Haskell to Scala

Tags: scala, haskell, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

I have defined a [monadic counter in Haskell](https://github.com/capitanbatata/sandbox/tree/master/monadic-counter) which I'm trying to translate to Scala, failing miserably so far. The problem in a nutshell is about implementing a counter as a state monad, which reads the counter increment constant from the environment, and logs the history of the counter (its sequence of values).

A friend of mine improved upon my solution, and came up with this simple solution:

```
newtype Counter = Counter Int deriving (Eq)

instance Show Counter where
  show (Counter i) = show i

incWith :: MonadState Counter m => Int -> m ()
incWith n = let incCounter n' (Counter i) = Counter $ i + n'
            in modify (incCounter n)

inc :: (MonadReader Int m, MonadState Counter m, MonadWriter [Counter] m) => m ()
inc = ask >>= incWith >> get >>= tell . (:[])

compute :: (MonadReader Int m, MonadState Counter m, MonadWriter [Counter] m) => m ()
compute =
  local (const 3) $ do
    inc
    inc
    inc
    local (const 5) $ do
      inc
      inc
```

I've tried [without success](https://github.com/capitanbatata/sandbox/tree/master/monadic-counter-scala-remix) to code this into Scala + (Cats | ScalaZ). The latest stable version of Cats lacks a `lift` method for `WriterT`. And with `ReaderWriterState` in `Scalaz` I could not figure out in a couple of hours how to use the `local` method. And that's only the begining ...

How this Haskell solution could be translated in a simple and elegant way? (to the extent allowed by the language).

Side note:

I'm still trying to figure out why I need to spend so much time to translate simple solutions from Haskell to Scala + FP libraries (Cats, Scalaz). In Haskell finding the instances and available functions of each type-class is a breeze, in Scala using IntelliJ, GitHub and StackOverflow this takes me days. So I'm wondering what am I doing wrong, and how could I improve this situation.

Comment: About your side note: You don't find the scala doc helpful in exploring the API?

Comment: So far not. The problem that I see a method defined as private to a class (take `local` above for instance), which means that you cannot use it directly but through one of the multiple instances of this private class. I don't think you can do this from the Scala doc alone.

Comment: Am not sure what you mean, but you can choose to see the private members of a class heirarchy by selecting the Visibility: Public | All option to All in the scala doc.

Comment: With regards to your side note, the Scala standard library does not come equipped with algebras such as Monad. If you want access to these facilities then either you have to hand code them yourself or as you did use Scalaz or Cats. However, due to the verbosity of the language and it's type system, it is comparatively more work to get the same thing in Haskell done in Scala. As Edward Kmett says, Haskell gives him a much higher power to weight ratio. Your frustrations prove that.

Comment: Power to weight ratio is maybe what I call signal to noise ratio ;) There are two major functional-programing (FP) libraries for Scala (Cats and Scalaz) which allows to do some first order FP. But as soon as I start composing types things start getting out of (my) control. I wonder how many programmers use also only this shallow core, while forfeiting the whole power of FP. I wonder how many more use Scala without knowing what FP is.

Comment: From personal experience (I code in Scala for food and water), every commercial Scala developer I have met does not code Scala in the FP paradigm. In one company I worked at, Scalaz was banned :). These Scala devs just happily code Scala with a view of it being a better Java so rather than modelling their solutions using FP constructs, they resort to the traditional OOP paradigm. There's nothing wrong with that but it's funny when some of them tell me they are coding in FP when all they have done is sprinkled a few `map` and `flatMap` in their code ;)

Comment: @Mika'il: where do the scala devs break most from FP? by not using pure functions, not using immutable values, etc? which is the part that is hard to stick to while doing FP in scala?

Comment: @Samar, I would say that the biggest barrier is that they are unable to transfer any of their OOP knowledge over to the FP paradigm. If we even take the most basic underlying concept of referential transparency in FP, immediately the imperative programmer is stumped. Firstly they have to understand that the notion of a function in FP is that of a mathematical function, not a function/procedure in the imperative sense (which sometimes has an implied environment baggaged with it).

Comment: If we take away the basic tools of an OOP programmer such as inheritance then you have almost crippled him. And we haven't even begun to talk about other FP bread and butter concepts in FP such as HOFs, lambda calculus, ADTs, algebra and co-algebras etc...

Comment: Thanks. I do not yet understand why OO style inheritance does not mix well with FP. Your point led me to do some search and came across this article about the refactoring approaches in functional vs OOP worlds. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ft5/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your intentions right, this translates to very easy and comprehensible piece of code:

```
  import scalaz._
  import Scalaz._
  val SM = ReaderWriterState.rwstMonad[Id, Int, List[String], Counter]

  case class Counter(value: Int)

  def incWith(n: Int): State[Counter, Unit] = for {
    v ← get[Counter]
    _ ← put(Counter(v.value + n))
  } yield ()

  def inc: IRWS[Int, List[String], Counter, Counter, Unit] = for {
    v ← SM.ask
    c ← SM.get
    _ ← SM.tell(List(s"Incrementing $c by $v "))
    _ ← SM.modify(counter ⇒ Counter(counter.value + v))
  } yield ()

  def compute: IRWS[Int, List[String], Counter, Counter, Unit] = {
    for {
      _ <- SM.local[Unit](i ⇒ 3)(for {
        _ ← inc
        _ ← inc
        _ ← inc
      } yield ())
      _ <- SM.local[Unit](i ⇒ 5)(for {
        _ ← inc
        _ ← inc
        _ ← inc
      } yield ())
    } yield ()
  }

  println(incWith(5)(Counter(0)))
  println(inc.run(4, Counter(0)))
  println(compute.run(0, Counter(0)))
```

Comment: Thanks (again ;)). I've modified it slightly and I pushed the resulting code to the repository I linked above. I have a couple of questions though. How could a newcomer to Scalaz could have figured out that you needed to use `ReaderWriterState.rwstMonad`. Also, how did you figure out that you needed to use IRWS? I'm really curious about this thought process, and how many experience in Scalaz it requires. If I have to continue programming Scala for food I'm thinking of making my own FP library...

Comment: BTW, If I try this with `Seq` the instance for `Monoid` for `Seq` is not found. Is this defined anywhere in Scalaz?

Comment: And finally, I'm really happy to see the two solutions (Haskell vs Scala) posted here, this clearly tells me I'm not wrong in doing everything in my power to reach a point in which I can make a living programming in Haskell. I hope this helps other people as well.

Comment: Welcome! Staring from shortest: I think `Monoid` for `Seq` is not defined anywhere directly, because `Seq` is not specific enough. Though, you can have monoids for `Vector` or for `IndSeq` and for any other `PlusEmpty` (`SemigroupK`) instance: `val x1 = Seq(1)

  implicit val m = scalaz.IndSeq.indSeqInstance.monoid[Int]
  IndSeq.fromSeq(x1) |+| IndSeq.fromSeq(x1)`

Comment: About IRWS - you can see that you need three monads - `Reader`, `Writer` and `State`. My general approach would be to go through transformers, but they are already implemented in specific traits `MonadReader`, `MonadWriter` etc.. Then just by following type hierarchies, you find out that `IRWST` implements all of them.  And by pressing dot in intellij on object ReaderWriterStateT (shows you available methods) I saw that `#rwst` returns you IRWST instance.